# Changing Format Of DatePicker Causes Validation Errors

Tags: django, datepicker

I'm using a datetime picker where a user chooses a month (MonthPickerInput).

models.py

```
birthdayMonth = models.DateField(null=True, default=now)
```

forms.py

```
from bootstrap_datepicker_plus import MonthPickerInput

class QuestionForm(forms.ModelForm):

    widgets = {
        'birthdayMonth': MonthPickerInput(
            options={
                "showClose": False,
                "showClear": False,
                "showTodayButton": False,
            }
        ),
    }
```

The user clicks on the form field, a calendar drops down and they select a month and year. MonthPicker automatically sets the day to '1'. This is fine on the back-end, but on the front-end in the form the user is filling out, it is displayed like this `2020-03-01`. I'd instead like it to be displayed like this `March 2020` (03-2020 would also be fine). To do this I added a field to `format` in `froms.py`:

```
widgets = {
    'birthdayMonth': MonthPickerInput(
        options={
            "format":"MMMM, YYYY",
        }
    ),
}
```

This displays correctly on the front-end, however form validation always fails (whenever I submit the form the calendar input is highlighted red but with no error message).

I printed the POST data in my views.py prior to hitting `if form.is_valid()` and prior to adding `format` to the widget it prints `2020-08-01`, whereas after adding `"format":"MMMM, YYYY"` it prints `08-2020`. I'm guessing this is causing the problem.

How can I change only the front-end display but leave the back-end in the original format so that my validation stops freaking out? I guess I'd need to use JQuery but all attempts have failed:

```
// this does nothing
$('#birthdayMonth').datepicker({
    format: 'MMMM/YYYY',
});

// I have tried many more things with JQuery but they do nothing or cause my code to go buggy (such as displaying two calendars on top of each other
```

The other thing I thought of doing is getting birthdayMonth from my POST data and adding the day field prior to passing it to my clean method. While I'm sure this would work, it's terribly hacky and there is bound to be a better way.

--EDIT--
If I add

```
birthdayMonth = forms.DateField(
    input_formats=['MMMM, YYYY'],
    widget=MonthPickerInput(format='MMMM, YYYY')
)
```

as Ben suggests it passes `December, 2020` to my view, which is why validation fails.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://django-bootstrap-datepicker-plus.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Usage.html?highlight=MonthPickerInput#customize-datepicker-format

"In order to use arbitrary formats you must specify the pattern to the field’s input_formats and the widget’s format."

```
 class BirthdayForm(forms.Form):
     birthdayMonth = forms.DateField(
         input_formats=['MMMM, YYYY'],
         widget=MonthPickerInput(format='MMMM, YYYY')
     )
```

---

Otherwise, there's no harm in adding the "day" field in a clean method:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-a-specific-field-attribute

```
 class BirthdayForm(forms.Form):
    # ...

    def clean_birthdayMonth(self):
        date_ = self.cleaned_data['birthdayMonth']
        date_ = date_.replace(day=1)

        return date_
```

---

If you can get "08-2020" or "August, 2020" from your form, you can easily convert to a python date time in the clean method

```
 class BirthdayForm(forms.Form):
    # ...

    def clean_birthdayMonth(self):
        import datetime

        dt_str = '08-2020'
        dt_obj = datetime.datetime.strptime(dt_str, '%m-%Y')
        
        dt_str = "August, 2020"
        dt_obj = datetime.datetime.strptime(dt_str, '%B, %Y')


        dt_str = self.cleaned_data['birthdayMonth']
        dt_obj = datetime.datetime.strptime(dt_str, '%B, %Y')

        return dt_obj
```

---

It does sound like the way to accomplish is to catch the data before the `form.is_valid()` is run.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#querydict-objects

```
post = request.POST.copy() # To get a mutable version

dt_str = post['birthdayMonth']  # "August, 2020"
dt_obj = datetime.datetime.strptime(dt_str, '%B, %Y')

post['birthdayMonth'] = dt_obj

# don't forget to update original POST
request.POST = post
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I had tried your first solution before (I should have mentioned that) and it displays an error ```unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'NoneType' and 'datetime.datetime'``` when I submit the page. I just added slightly more context to my question above, but I tried your second solution as ```class QuestionForm(forms.Form) def clean_birthdayMonth(self):``` and also by doing it just within ```def clean(self)``` and it didn't display an error, but the form is rejected and the datepicker input is highlighted as red but with no ValidationError :(

Comment: If you add a `clean_birthdayMonth()` method, what is returned in `self.cleaned_data['birthdayMonth']` ?

Comment: I added the ```def clean_birthdayMonth(self):``` method and it isn't even called (the form fails with 'enter a valid date'). It is called if I remove ```format='MMMM, YYYY'```. For further testing I added a clean method: ```clean(self): cleaned_data = super(BirthdayForm, self).clean()     print(cleaned_data.get('know_ielts_test_date'))``` and the page again fails with 'enter a valid date' and the print statement prints ```True```

Comment: @Brenden, It does sound like the way to accomplish in this case to catch the data before the `form.is_valid()` is run. I added some example code for that too.

Comment: Thank you very much, it took a while but we got there. There's no way I would have figured that out. I appreciate it

Answer (score 1):

in settings.py set the required time format

```
DATE_INPUT_FORMATS = ['%d/%m/%Y']
```

and also make

```
USE_L10N = False
```

in `forms.py` import settings

```
from django.conf import settings
```

Then add in `class form_name()`

```
birth_date = forms.DateField(widget=forms.DateInput,input_formats= settings.DATE_INPUT_FORMATS)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Ben has answered my question, though I still think I will end up implementing this as I would like to change the date format from ```'%m/%d/%Y'``` to ```'%d/%m/%Y'```.

Comment: @Brenden have you changed `USE_LI0N =False`?

Comment: Not yet, I am just fixing my unit tests as adding the code Ben gave broke some of them, then I will look into this :)

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to just leave your backend as it is, and in your template you can do the necessary formatting, for example:

```
{{birthdayMonth|date:"F Y"}}
```

The F will give you the full month, and the Y the full year.

For more details and other formats, you can refer to the documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/builtins/

Comment: Thankyou, however I am wanting to change the way it's output in my form